# Move Files from one folder to another without using -Recurse

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script where all I want to do is move files of a certain type from the folder specified to a destination folder. Unfortunately this doesn't work without -Recurse contained which is not the functionality I want to achieve. If I include -Recurse it starts to move images from "D:/Photos/x/" etc. All i want to do is move files from "D:/Photos" to the destination

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Photos" -Include *.png, *.jpeg, *.jpg |
Move-Item -Destination "D:\Photos\Powershell Task" -Force
```

Answer (score 3):

The `-Include` parameter without `-Recurse` does not work.

However, there is another way to have the `-Include` do what you want (namely filter on more than one extension) and that is to add `\*` to the Path.

In your case:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Photos\*" -Include *.png, *.jpeg, *.jpg |
Move-Item -Destination "D:\Photos\Powershell Task" -Force
```

Mind you: The destination path `D:\Photos\Powershell Task` needs to exist.

Answer (score 3):

Solution :

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Photos\*" -Include *.png, *.jpeg, *.jpg | Move-Item -Destination "D:\Photos\Powershell Task" -Force
```

Explanation : 
When selecting Get-ChildItem to use include you must have -recursion selected OR define what the include is represented using wildcards in the -path.
This case **D:\Photos\*** is defining to get all children in D:\Photos that have both a name and extension then you are filtering those by using -include to say only the ones with extensions .jpg .png